# How to use a Datareader Inside a Class using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, data-binding

I have `SqlDataReader` that was sitting in a page's code behind (well actually a web user control). I'd like to move this code to a separate class which the user control calls. But how do I bind the data from the class to the on page repeater?

Is this an acceptable concept?

Here's my code moved to a class:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public ShoppingCart(int ShoppingCartHeadID)
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        conn = new SqlConnection(iceConns.iconn);

        comm = new SqlCommand("Ordering.sl_ShoppingCartContents", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@shoppingCartHeadID", SqlDbType.Int));
        comm.Parameters["@shoppingCartHeadID"].Value = ShoppingCartHeadID;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            Cart.DataSource = reader; //This ain't gonna work!
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                Cart.DataBind(); //This ain't gonna work!
                varCartStatus = true;
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error trapping
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should really have some using statements around the SqlConnection conn, SqlCommand comm, SqlDataReader reader

Comment: Hear hear. Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx#adonetbest_topic4   You need the section under "Always Close Connections and DataReaders"

Comment: @Manatherin is this what you mean?

`using (conn = new SqlConnection(iceConns.iconn))
            {
                comm = new SqlCommand("Ordering.sl_ShoppingCartContents", conn);
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@shoppingCartHeadID", SqlDbType.Int));
                comm.Parameters["@shoppingCartHeadID"].Value = ShoppingCartHeadID;
            }` -Cheers...

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb a bit like https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/7445285.txt?w=abed9456 (there may be a few connection closed and stuff thats no longer required but more to show the usings)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create an entity object for the returned data. Then you can bind any control to a List of the object you created.

Create a Cart object with the properties that map to your database table.
Then create a class like CartRepository that will have a method called GetCartById(CartId). This method will do the work above, but instead of trying to bind anything here you are simply going to fill your Cart objects. The return a list of those objects and you can bind that list to any control.

```
public class Cart
{
    //Properties from cart - Just using name as an example.
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class CartRepository
{
    public List<Cart> GetById(int cartId)
    {
        List<Cart> carts = new List<Cart>();

        // Do all sql work including setting up connection, command, ect.

        while(reader.read())
        {
            // Map your reader to your cart object.
            Cart c = new Cart();
            c.name = reader["name"].ToString();
            carts.add(c);
        }

        return carts;
    }
}
```

Now from your code just bind your control to the List returned from the repository object.

```
 myControl1.DataSource = CartRepository.GetById(cartId);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is it possible to give me an example as I don't know what an entity object is?!

Comment: @comfortablynumb: it's just a class with real properties (of the propert type) instead of an anonymous "DataRow", that holds the same data.

Comment: It's just a class with properties. Say in your database you have a Customer table with columns for name, email and datecreated. In your application you would create a class with properties for name, email and datecreated to mirror that table. Then when your datareader is reading the returned results, you are simply going to create a new Customer and fill the properties with the values the reader has.

Comment: If nobody else helps, I can write up a small example later. I don't have much time right now. Sorry.

Comment: @sinclairchase. Thanks, but the penny isn't dropping here! I know I'm running before I can walk here. Whoosh, right over my head! Really sorry.

Comment: @sinclairchase Thanks for the code example. Gonna give it a try!

Comment: @sinclairchase The Penny dropped and got it working perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The 'modern' way to go is to bind your Repeater to a collection like a Generic List `List<T>`, probably a `List<Order>` returned by your ShoppingCart class, via say a `GetOrders(int customerId)` method or similar.

So your data access routine will populate a List:

```
List<Orders> lst = new List<Orders>();  

while (rdr.Read()){
    Order o = new Order( <populate from the reader's fields e.g. rdr["OrderId"] (remember to cast accordingly) ...);  
    lst.Add(o);    

}
```

...

And then, in your web page/control you do something like

```
Cart.DataSource = ShoppingCart.GetOrders(...);
Cart.DataBind();
```

You'll need get/set properties in your custom Order class to facilitate databinding.

HTH. Here's a cut of v. basic demo application if you want to see this in action: http://www.largedocument.com/1/ec24da47/BindingToCollectionsDemo.zip

Comment: I understand the code placed in the control, but I don't understand the list bit at all. Sorry!

Comment: The list is just a collection of objects of your choice e.g.

List<string> lstStrings = new List<strings>(); //lets you store strings.  

List<int> lstInts = new List<int>();   //Ints

For now, think of it as a bucket with smarts that keep your objects in. It does much more besides. You could add your Order objects to an Array instead and Bind to that if you wanted to - List<T> (Generic Lists) have a lot of additional, v. useful functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the download. I've set things up but I'm not getting any any data back. No errors.

Comment: When I added the While Reader, VS asked to add a stub. and it added the following to Cart class:  `private object p;
 private object p_2;
 private object p_3;
 private object p_4;public Cart(object p, object p_2, object p_3, object p_4)
  {
   
   this.p = p;
   this.p_2 = p_2;
   this.p_3 = p_3;
   this.p_4 = p_4;
  }` So I dont know if I've done something wrong.

Comment: How did you add the `While` block? And what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: `conn.Open();
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
     Cart c = new Cart(reader["shoppingCartID"], reader["shoppingCartQty"], reader["shoppingCartPrice"], reader["shoppingCartPrice"]);
     lst.Add(c);  
    }
    
    reader.Close();` VS2010

Comment: Cool. Out of interest, what was the issue?

Comment: Basically I had written the While block wrong without casting. A definite lesson learned!

Comment: "Experience is simply the name we give our mistakes."
Oscar Wilde 

;-)